# How do i convert from PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher to default string formatting?

Tags: android, formatting

I'm using an edit text for getting a phone number - It gets formatted using PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher, and I want to convert it to the default string format.

number = (123) 456-7890

I want to convert it to "1234567890"

```
etPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
String number = etRegisPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `number = etRegisPhoneNumber.getText().toString().replaceAll( "[^\\d]","")`; This will remove non-digits.